# 'ngx-bootstrap-treeview' is not a known element in Component Test

Tags: angular, routes, cucumber, karma-jasmine

I have implemented `ngx-bootstrap-treeview` and it is working fine as a functionality but when i execute my component test to verify UI then it start throwing error.
[image]

I have declared the Module in `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgxBootstrapTreeviewModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap-treeview';
imports: [..., NgxBootstrapTreeviewModule],
exports: [..., NgxBootstrapTreeviewModule]
```

If I import same module in my test component `abc.component.steps.ts` then it start throwing new errors:

[image]

Library link : https://github.com/Zokelion/ngx-bootstrap-treeview

Comment: Do you have any other modules other than app.module ?

Comment: Yes. Shared.module but that is already imported in app.module and in similar way i have imported other modules and that are working fine.

I have imported RouterTestingModule then I start facing error `root of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolved it by importing below dependencies in my testcase file `abc.component.steps.ts` .

> ```
> RouterTestingModule,
> NgxBootstrapTreeviewModule,
> BrowserAnimationsModule
> ```

I hope it may help someone!